# Why do I see more remote branches locally then I've got on github?

Tags: git, github, branch

I've got a git repo hosted on github. When I do `git branch` locally I get just the three branches you see in the output below:

```
$ git fetch
$ git branch
* develop
  kramer65/feature-branch
  master
```

I then logged into github and on there I see it just has 5 branches:

[image]

So now I did a `git branch -a` locally, which shows my 3 local branches, plus about 40 remote branches:

[image]

So then I tried to remove one of the remote branches, but I can't:

```
$ git push origin :kramer65-feature-branch
error: unable to delete 'kramer65-feature-branch': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:MyOrganisation/therepo.git'
```

Any idea why I still see these repos with a `git branch -a`?

Comment: I guess you didn't run `git fetch -p`

Comment: @Danh - Nailed it. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possible scenario is someone create a branch for development, you run a:

```
git fetch
```

will fetch all of those branches. When that feature branch had been merged, they were deleted, and `git fetch` didn't remove it. You need

```
git fetch -p
```

or

```
git fetch --prune
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `remove` any `remote-tracking` references that `no longer exist` on the remote.

Try this:

```
$ git fetch --prune
$ git branch -a

# more info
$ git fetch --help
```